# New android Support Design Library, scroll tablayout offscreen not working

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, android-support-design

Trying to use the new support design library. In my layout I want the `ToolBar` to stay at the top of the screen, but have the `TabLayout` go off the screen when the user scrolls down. But it looks like the `ViewPager` goes underneath the `AppBarLayout`. I used this blog post for reference
https://medium.com/ribot-labs/exploring-the-new-android-design-support-library-b7cda56d2c32

This is the layout, within the `ViewPager` holds `Fragments` that consist of recycler views

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/material_grey50"
android:clickable="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabLayout" />


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_list"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:tabGravity="center" />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_post"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_videocam_white_36dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
    app:fabSize="normal" />

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Here the layout_behavior works with specific controls like recycler view or nested scrollview. see [demo](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set this in the viewpager:

`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Comment: I did that as well with no effect

Comment: This may not be it, but it works fine in my project when the ViewPager is the last child while AppBarLayout is the first child of the CoordinatorLayout. Try reordering them in that order. Also, I'm seeing the `</RelativeLayout>` tag add the bottom of your snippet so if that were leftovers from previous deletion, try to delete that.

Comment: hmm reordering doesn't work either, are you using design-support 22.2.0 and support lib 22.2? Would it matter if this layout is in a fragment?

Comment: Yeap. I even used it in fragment. On second thought, remove that unnecessary relativelayout and just use layout_anchor and layout_gravity instead on the FAB.